# Latex codes for some other chemistry symbols

Tags: symbols, chemistry

How can i write some of these symbols in Latex?

1. Quadruple Bond or even 5 or 6 bonds as evident from Wikipedia articles:
   ([Quadruple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadruple_bond))([Quintuple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quintuple_bond))([Sextuple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sextuple_bond))
2. Bent / Banana bonds (bonds having a curved kind of structure due to strain)

Please reply...Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX-sx! It would be useful to know what support packages, if any, you are using. (I'd go with `chemformula` myself: multiple bonds are easy enough and I think banana ones are quite doable once I remember the correct TikZ code.)

Comment: related http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/260839/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on your needs this is rather straight-forward with the `chemformula` package and a little TikZ:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemformula}

\NewChemBond{quadruple}{
  \foreach \i in {-.15em,-.05em,.05em,.15em}{
    \draw[chembond]
      ([yshift=\i]chemformula-bond-start) -- ([yshift=\i]chemformula-bond-end) ;
  }
}
\NewChemBond{quintuple}{
  \foreach \i in {-.16em,-.08em,0em,.08em,.16em}{
    \draw[chembond]
      ([yshift=\i]chemformula-bond-start) -- ([yshift=\i]chemformula-bond-end) ;
  }
}
\NewChemBond{sextuple}{
  \foreach \i in {-.2em,-.12em,-.04em,.04em,.12em,.2em}{
    \draw[chembond]
      ([yshift=\i]chemformula-bond-start) -- ([yshift=\i]chemformula-bond-end) ;
  }
}

\NewChemBond{banana}{
  \draw[chembond]
    (chemformula-bond-start)
      parabola[bend pos=.5] bend +(0,.5ex)
    (chemformula-bond-end) ;
}

\begin{document}

\ch{X\bond{quadruple}X}\par
\ch{X\bond{quintuple}X}\par
\ch{X\bond{sextuple}X}\par
\ch{X\bond{banana}X}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to draw n-bonds (n>1) with chemfig:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{nbond/.style args={#1}{%
        draw=none,%
        decoration={%
            markings,%
            mark=at position 0 with {\coordinate (CFstart@) at (0,0);},
            mark=at position 1 with {%
                \foreach\CF@i in{0,1,...,\number\numexpr#1-1}{%
                    \pgfmathsetmacro\CF@nbondcoeff{\CF@i-0.5*(#1-1)}%
                    \draw ([yshift=\CF@nbondcoeff\CF@double@sep]CFstart@)--(0,\CF@nbondcoeff\CF@double@sep);
                    }%
                }
            },
        postaction={decorate}
    }
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\chemfig{A-[1,,,,nbond=4]B-[:-30,,,,nbond=5]C-[6,,,,nbond=6]D}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't now if quadruple bonds can be made with chemfig but the curved bonds are no problem.

With the tikz library "pathmorphing" and the following code

```
\chemfig{A-[,3,,,decorate,decoration=snake]B}
```

you get this:

[image]

Other shapes can be made with nodes.
Try this code for example

```
\chemfig{@{a}A-[,,,,draw=none]@{b}B}
\chemmove{\draw[-](a)..controls +(45:7mm) and +(225:7mm)..(b);}
```

to get the following:

[image]

Explanation:

```
225:7mm
```

225 is the angle and 7mm is the amplitude of the bond. Our bond enters B in an angle of 225° and the curve has it's minimum at y=-7mm.

Demo code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\begin{document}
\schemestart
\chemfig{A-[,3,,,decorate,decoration=snake]B}
\schemestop
\par
\schemestart
\chemfig{@{a}A-[,,,,draw=none]@{b}B}
    \chemmove{\draw[-](a)..controls +(45:7mm) and +(225:7mm)..(b);}
\schemestop
\end{document}
```

Please make sure to run the compilation twice to make the curved bonds appear!

Comment: You might be interested in this http://www.mychemistry.eu/2012/03/wavy-bonds/