# Special "chemical bond" symbol

Tags: symbols, chemistry

I would like to use a symbol in a chemical reaction equation which represents a solid's surface.

A common symbol used for this purpose is '>' or the `\equiv` symbol, but what I would like is actually something like the `\equiv` symbol but with the length of em-dash (basically like 3 em-dashes stacked on-top of one another).

Ultimately though, I would actually like a symbol with 5 lines on-top of each other, the height of a normal capitalized character.

Do you guys know of any such symbol that may exist? Or, is it possible to 'build' something like this?

Comment: It can be done  putting an `=` symbol on top of the `equiv` symbol, but it would be slightly higher than a capital letter.

Comment: There are specific packages for that, see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/260839. Example:  `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemformula}
\NewChemBond{quindruple}{
  \foreach \i in {-.3em,-0.15em,.0em,.15em,0.3em}{
    \draw[chembond]
      ([yshift=\i]chemformula-bond-start) -- ([yshift=\i]chemformula-bond-end) ;
  }
}
\begin{document}

\ch{Ct\bond{quindruple}Ct}

\end{document}`

Answer (score 6):

Here's a `chemformula` solution:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{chemformula}

\NewChemBond{quintuple}{
  \foreach \i in {-.7ex,-.35ex,0ex,.35ex,.7ex}{
    \draw[chembond]
      ([yshift=\i]chemformula-bond-start) -- ([yshift=\i]chemformula-bond-end) ;
  }
}
\NewChemCompoundProperty{|}{\bond{quintuple}}

\begin{document}

\setchemformula{bond-length=1em}

\ch{Ti\bond{quintuple}Ti}

\ch{A-B + A=B + A+B + A|B}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Is this close to what you want?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{stackengine}

\newcommand{\mybond}{\mathrel{\scalebox{1.5}[0.84]{$\stackMath\stackinset{c}{-1.4pt}{c}{4.3pt}{=}{\equiv}$}}}

\begin{document}

\[\mathrm{N}\mybond \text{---}\]%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, thanks Bernard and Schrödinger's cat, that's exactly it. Nice answers guys!

Answer (score 5):

Thanks for all the great leads guys. I liked @unbonpetit's [response](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/260950/54526) with the long lines (admittedly longer than `em-dash` like I initially wanted), so I decided to modify the code a bit and got a really nice result:

[image: ]]

What's nice is you can play around with the positioning and I was able to get it slightly (vertically) off-center so that it lies closer to the baseline. Anyway, here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\def\fivebondsep{1.25pt}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations}
\pgfdeclaredecoration{ddddb}{initial}{
    \state{initial}[width=\pgfdecoratedremainingdistance]
        {\foreach\i in{1.5,0.5,-0.5,-1.5,-2.5}{%
            \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{0pt}{\i*\fivebondsep}}\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgfdecoratedremainingdistance}{\i*\fivebondsep}}}
        }
    \state{final}
        {}
}
\tikzset{5bond/.style={decorate,decoration=ddddb}}
\begin{document}
\chemfig{Ti-[,,,,5bond]Ti}
\end{document}
```

You don't even have to rename the ("fourbond...", etc.) definitions of course, but I just did it for completeness.

I did a similar one for a triple bond too. Thanks again for all the great answers everyone!